# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I have the following test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles({ "DataTC", "test" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BaseTestConfiguration.class, DataTestConfiguration.class, JpaConfiguration.class, PropertyPlaceholderConfiguration.class })
public class RegularDayToTimeSlotsTest {
...
```

The issue seems to come from the BaseTestConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.bignibou" }, excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = RooRegexFilter.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class), @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = ControllerAdvice.class) })
public class BaseTestConfiguration {

}
```

I systematically get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$bb4ceb44.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$22(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$bb4ceb44$$FastClassByCGLIB$$368bb5c1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$bb4ceb44.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 43 more
```

I am not sure how to get around this issue. Somehow Spring is looking for a ServletContext when I run the test and I get the above exception...

Answer (score 142, accepted):

One of your `@Configuration` classes is obviously annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`. That's how `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` ends up in your stack trace, since it is *imported* by `@EnableWebMvc`.

So although you *think* you don't need a `WebApplicationContext` (and hence a `ServletContext`), you in fact do need it simply because you are loading an application context with `@EnableWebMvc`.

You have two options:

- Compose the configuration classes for your integration test so that you are not including the web-related configuration (i.e., the `@Configuration` class(es) annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`).
- Annotate your test class with `@WebAppConfiguration` as suggested in other comments above.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: I tried to go for the first option you kindly suggested by excluding the @EnableWebMvc-annotated class with an exclude filter i.e. with an filtertype=assignable type but to no avail...

Comment: Please also note that I do not include the `@Configuration` class annotated with `@EnableWebMvc` in the above test. It is being picked up by the `@ComponentScan` in BaseTestConfiguration...

Comment: Any tips for the case where this is happening on spring-boot:run (my tests are running fine)?

Comment: Sounds like a completely different question to me. Ask a new one and tag it spring-boot?

Comment: Ensure that you are loading the context with an AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader (if using config classes), like this: `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class, classes = {ConfigClass.class})`

Comment: Same issue! But here is how mycase was (for future reference) : in the TestConfig I had
@ComponentScan(basePackages="app")
and in app package there was a config file which had @EnableWebMvc in it !

Comment: @ferrarimarco, you do _not_ need to declare `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader`. It is enabled by default whenever you declare the `classes` attribute of `@ContextConfiguration`. See the "_Context configuration with annotated classes_" section of the testing chapter in the Spring reference manual for details: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig

Comment: @SamBrannen you are right. I was forcing `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` in a superclass. This behaviour is described in the documentation: _If not specified, the loader will be inherited from the first superclass that is annotated with `@ContextConfiguration` and specifies an explicit loader. If no class in the hierarchy specifies an explicit loader, a default loader will be used instead._

Answer (score 38):

It seems like you are missing

```
@WebAppConfiguration
```

from your test class.

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) states

> The resource base path is used behind the scenes to create a
>   MockServletContext which serves as the ServletContext for the test’s
>   WebApplicationContext.

Typically a Servlet container would provide the `ServletContext`. Since you are in a testing environment, you need a fake. `@WebAppConfiguration` provides that.

Answer (score 11):

For you to instantiate the Servlet context, you would have to use the annotation.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
```

A class-level annotation that is used to declare that the ApplicationContext loaded for an integration test should be a WebApplicationContext. The mere presence of @WebAppConfiguration on a test class ensures that a WebApplicationContext will be loaded for the test, using the default value of "file:src/main/webapp" for the path to the root of the web application (i.e., the resource base path). The resource base path is used behind the scenes to create a MockServletContext which serves as the ServletContext for the test’s WebApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error but whilst running the application normally rather than trying to run tests.

It turns out if you're making use of a custom `PermissionEvaluator` then you need to declare it in a separate `@Configuration` class to the one with your main Spring security configuration in.

See: [How do I add method based security to a Spring Boot project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638462/how-do-i-add-method-based-security-to-a-spring-boot-project)

There is also an open Github issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4875