# Failed to Load ApplicationContext during Spring unit test

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-java-config

I am trying to run a Junit functional test using Springs java-config for my application context. I am not sure if it is a problem with Spring or Junit... just not sure.. The application runs fine on my local server (hitting the db), but when I try to run my test it bombs out.
I just moved from xml to java config so I can always import my xml context files (which I know works in my tests) but going forward I would rather just use my java config.

**My Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
        classes = { AppConfig.class, ServletConfig.class })
@EnvironmentConfiguration(db2Enabled = true)
public class EventDAOTest {
```

**The StackTrace**

```
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:45 AM com.aoins.config.CachingPropertyFileReader <clinit>
SEVERE: ERROR - Configuration Framework not detected!
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:45 AM com.aoins.config.CachingPropertyFileReader readFile
SEVERE: Unable to build property reference for: (common).
2014-02-04 11:51:45,510 | DEBUG |         : | LoggerConfigurer | Msg: Log4j configured with: 'C:/javalog/log4jPCProperties.xml'
2014-02-04 11:51:48,248 | INFO  |         : | EnvironmentConfigurer | Msg: DB2 Connection was established
2014-02-04 11:51:48,279 | INFO  |         : | EnvironmentConfigurer | Msg: CICS Connection was established
2014-02-04 11:51:48,279 | INFO  |         : | EnvironmentConfigurer | Msg: JMS Connection was NOT established according to the configuration
2014-02-04 11:51:48,279 | INFO  |         : | EnvironmentConfigurer | Msg: EMail Connection was NOT established according to the configuration
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@215d215d: startup date [Tue Feb 04 11:51:48 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/associates],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.associate.AssociateDataController.retrieveAssociates(java.lang.String)
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/associateFilterTypes],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.associatefiltertype.AssociateFilterDataController.retrieveEventFilterTypes()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/associateFilterTypes/{pTypeCode}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.associatefiltertype.AssociateFilterDataController.retrieveEventFilterType(java.lang.String) throws com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.associatefiltertype.AssociateFilterTypeNotFoundException
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/dateFilterTypes],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.datefiltertype.DateFilterDataController.retrieveEventFilterTypes()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/dateFilterTypes/{pTypeCode}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.datefiltertype.DateFilterDataController.retrieveEventFilterType(java.lang.String) throws com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.datefiltertype.DateFilterTypeNotFoundException
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/departments/{pDepartmentCode}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.department.DepartmentDataController.retrieveDepartment(java.lang.String) throws com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.department.DepartmentNotFoundException
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/divisions],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.division.DivisionDataController.retrieveDivisionsDepartments()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventController.showEvents()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[//Test],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventController.showTests()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/events/{pEventId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventDataController.retrieveEvent(java.lang.Integer)
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/events],methods=[GET],params=[page && associateFilter && dateFilter],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventDataController.retrieveFiltered(com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.associatefiltertype.AssociateFilterType,com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.datefiltertype.DateFilterType,java.lang.Integer,com.aoins.sales.user.User)
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/events],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventDataController.saveEvent(com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventBeanImpl,com.aoins.sales.user.User) throws com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventException
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/Public/events],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.Event> com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventDataPublicController.doList()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/Public/events/{pEventId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.Event com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventDataPublicController.doRetrieve(java.lang.Integer)
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/eventTypes],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.eventtype.EventTypeDataController.retrieveEventTypes()
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Data/eventTypes/{pTypeCode}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.eventtype.EventTypeDataController.retrieveEventType(java.lang.String) throws com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.eventtype.EventTypeNotFoundException
Feb 4, 2014 11:51:49 AM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@20c820c8] to prepare test instance [com.aoins.sales.eventplanning.events.EventDAOTest@f7e0f7e]
Throwable occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:326)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at com.aoins.func.tester.AOSpringFunctionalTester.run(AOSpringFunctionalTester.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:67)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:330)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$104f0b6f.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$22(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$104f0b6f$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ff8cbba8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$104f0b6f.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 42 more
```

So it appears that it is not finding the *configuration framework*, but I have been following the reference guides and API... not sure what I am missing or not configuring correctly. I am using Spring 4.0, Junit 4.10

Also, for each test it throws this error. That to me means it is trying to load the ApplicationContext again (prepareRefresh)... once for each @Test -- that also doesn't make sense to me...

Here are some resources:

- [ContextConfiguration API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html)
- [Spring Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit)
- [Spring blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll need to annotate your test class with

```
@WebAppConfiguration
```

so that the test environment provides your `WebApplicationContext` with a mock `ServletContext` required by your MVC configuration.

Comment: I tried that option, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516683/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-a-servletcontext-is-required-to-configure-de .

Comment: @Prancer And what happened?

Comment: Also, it is throwing this on my app-context first, not the servlet-context. To my understanding of the API, the ConfigurationContext can load multiple contexts, my servletConfig imports my webConfig with the EnableWebMvc and that is also fine and in which case, the WebAppConfiguration won't be needed. -- but I tried it anyways :)

Comment: @Prancer `@EnableWebMvc` generates some beans behind the scenes. Some of these require a `ServletContext`, for example the `defaultServletHandlerMapping` bean you see in your exception stack trace. `@WebAppConfiguration` is needed specifically for that, to provide a mock `ServletContext`.

Comment: Does this require Servlet 3.0 ? I received this after moving around some configurations.`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig`

Comment: @prance You'll definitely need the servlet api on your class path. I'm not sure it has to be 3.0. I'm away from a PC right now.

Comment: Got it working and here is what I posted. <br/> `@WebAppConfiguration("WebConfig")
@ContextHierarchy({
 @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = ServletConfig.class)
})`<br/> I have tested with both with and without the @ContextHierarchy and @ContextConfiguration(loader...). With or without those function correctly. <br/> I did need the @WebAppConfiguration. I'll be honest with you I still don't understand why I didn't need this with my xml-config.

Comment: @Prancer Without seeing your XML config, I can't really help you. Did the XML contain `<mvc:annotation-driven>`. That is the equivalent of `@EnableWebMvc`. If you had that, then you would have needed `@WebAppConfiguration` as well.

Comment: Anyways, I updated my IDE to STS 3.4 and (for some reason) that told me my tx bean could not be found, _Caught exception while retrieving transaction manager_.
After I fixed that the test ran fine. Thanks for the comments. You have my vote. PS, I did try your solution given in my first comment before posting this question :O -- Spring just had me searching for the wrong issue...

Answer (score 91):

I moved from spring 3.2.0 to 4.0.3 and had to update my javax.servlet dependency (in maven) from servlet 2.5 to servlet 3.0.1. The final dependency was

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
```

Then it worked

Comment: This also worked for me.  but. how did you know?  I couldn't find this version on maven central (http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22javax.servlet%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javax.servlet-api%22) .  Is there a reference for which version of spring.x goes with spring.y ?

Comment: This does not answer the question, on its own. Upgrading to 3.0.1 would not solve the error they are getting.

Comment: @Sotirios: This solution really helped. The reason I can make out is javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig is not present in servlet api < 3.0,.1

Answer (score 23):

Since a couple people mentioned Servlet version issues:

As of Spring 4.0 the set of mocks is now based on the Servlet 3.0 API.

You have two options:

1. use 3.2.x spring-test dependency

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2. upgrade to servlet 3.0

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to test Spring 4.0 with Spring-test 3.2.14. Is it? I upgraded to servlet 3.0 and it worked, so upvoting.

Comment: It worked by changing the dependency of Servlet API - i am using Spring 4. With Spring 3 no issue was found. Confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

In gradle

```
testCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
```

Note: this works for me even though I'm testing against Google App Engine (servlet 2.4) Because it is only used for tests.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11049

Comment: I run in a servlet 2.5 application. I haven't upgraded to use of servlet 3.0 yet. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 2):

the way to solve such problems - 
try to force import of the notFoundClass manually, by smth like:
Class c = javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig.class;

so Idea+Maven suggested me to add maven dependency, i agreed. And suddenly in pom.xml the code appeared:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

then i removed "Class c = javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig.class;" - there is no need in it, rather than to load necessary dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a MockServletContext to your test applicationContext.
The MockServletContext can be found in spring-test.jar (or maven dependency). You should (obviously) not use this in production, but only register it in a context that you include in your test context.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ActiveProfiles({"{test", "default"}) annotation