# Does not find the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError class: javax / servlet / SessionCookieConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have dependencies in the project

```
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
    exclude group: "org.apache.tomcat", module: "tomcat-jdbc"
    exclude group: "org.hibernate", module: "hibernate-entitymanager"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
compile("org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa")
compile("org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor")
compile("com.google.api-client:google-api-client")
compile("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty")
compile("com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive")

   // dependencies from the inherited module (compile(project("..."))
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    api("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator")
    api("commons-validator:commons-validator")
    api("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava")
```

I wanted to do integration tests so I added dependencies

```
testCompile("com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:1.3.0")
testCompile("org.dbunit:dbunit:2.5.4")
```

I created the basic configuration class

```
/**
 * Spring configuration class for integration tests.
 */
@Configuration 
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
@ComponentScan
public class PopcornCoreTestApplication {}
```

and an abstract class

```
/**
 * Base class to save on configuration.
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PopcornCoreTestApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@TestExecutionListeners(
        {
                DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
                TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
                TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
        }
)
public abstract class DBUnitTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    /**
     * Clean out the db after every test.
     */
    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        this.userRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

and some example test to check if it works

```
/**
 * Integration tests for UserPersistenceServiceImpl.
 */
public class UserPersistenceServiceImplIntegrationTests extends DBUnitTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private UserPersistenceService userPersistenceService;

    /**
     * Setup.
     */
   @Test
    public void setup() {
        Assert.assertThat(this.userRepository.count(), Matchers.is(0L));
    }
}
```

and its not working. I am getting the test start pop

```
    lip 04, 2018 6:30:10 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration
INFO: Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.service.UserPersistenceServiceImplIntegrationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
lip 04, 2018 6:30:10 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader generateDefaultLocations
INFO: Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.service.UserPersistenceServiceImplIntegrationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
lip 04, 2018 6:30:11 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@769e7ee8, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5276e6b0, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@71b1176b, com.github.springtestdbunit.TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener@6193932a]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig
...

lip 04, 2018 6:30:12 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@769e7ee8] to prepare test instance [com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.service.UserPersistenceServiceImplIntegrationTests@402bba4f]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig
```

on pastebin all error https://pastebin.com/8kC4Mkm6

I tried to add a dependency

```
javax.servlet-api
```

but it did not help and the same mistake is still there.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to Load ApplicationContext during Spring unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21561432/5221149)

Answer (score 7):

for all the mvn users, please add below dependency to the pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

**SessionCookieConfig** class appears in servlet-api from version 3.0.

To fix your issues just add this dependency to your **build.gradle** file

```
testCompile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
```