# When customizing Tomcat: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application that already runs: I can curl to hit the endpoints, etc.

I'm trying to configure it for use with HTTPS per the [spring boot reference guide (pg 115)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf) and added code like so to my @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
@Inject
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer tomcatCustomizer(@Value("${keystore.file}") String keystoreFile,
                                                           @Value("${keystore.password}") String keystorePassword,
                                                           @Value("${keystore.type}") String keystoreType,
                                                           @Value("${keystore.alias}") String keystoreAlias) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    final String absoluteKeystoreFile = ResourceUtils.getFile(keystoreFile).getAbsolutePath();
    EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer tomcatCustomizer = (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) -> {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory;
        containerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) (Connector connector) -> {
            connector.setSecure(true);
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", absoluteKeystoreFile);
            connector.setAttribute("keystorePass", keystorePassword);
            connector.setAttribute("keystoreType", keystoreType);
            connector.setAttribute("keyAlias", keystoreAlias);
            connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
            connector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
            connector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
        });
    };

    return tomcatCustomizer;
}
```

However, with only this code addition, my previously working app now gets the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f697b5e2.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$23(<generated>)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f697b5e2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$972d2616.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
at org.springfr.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f697b5e2.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
... 16 more
```

I verified that the properties are coming in correctly to the method, and tried adding/removing @WebAppConfiguration as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516683/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-a-servletcontext-is-required-to-configure-de)

My gradle file is using spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.0.RELEASE.

The questions are: How do I correctly configure https with spring boot? Why does my the app work when I don't try to configure tomcat, and break when I do try to configure tomcat?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just after posting this question, I discovered the answer:

For how to correctly configure https with spring boot: The code listed above was originally added to my @Configuration SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. When I moved the tomcat customization to its own @Configuration class, it worked.

For why: Presumably the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is called earlier in the application context lifecycle than the rest of the @Configurations.

Comment: Correct. Security lives in a `Filter` and they have to be registered early.

Comment: I'm struggling with switching certain configuration parts in separate `@Configuration` over and over again. Would you please have a link which describes the behaviour you mentioned? Or some generic source of info on how the order of `@Configuration` works and what should be taken care of?

Comment: Correct, I add this into WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it won't work. after change to @Configuration it works.