# Configure own messageSource with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot and was using the `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration` but now for the messageSource I want to define a `parentMessageSource` using a  `ResourceBundleMessageSource`. However, I can't see how to do this with boot's auto configuration. I've tried excluding the `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class` but am getting the exception below when trying to define my own `messageSource` bean
any help greatly would be appreciated.

```
2015-07-20 09:33:31,811 [BOF37942::] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.lv.gi.br.Application.main(Application.java:31) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:426) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e80e61d6.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$32() ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e80e61d6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3900e0ca.invoke() ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e80e61d6.defaultServletHandlerMapping() ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I had both the 'messageSource' and 'parentMessageSource' @Bean's defined in a WebFlowConfig @Configuration class. I moved these two @Bean's to their own MessageConfig @Configuration class and everything worked! My inspiration came from a similar issue here: [How do I add method based security to a Spring Boot project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638462/how-do-i-add-method-based-security-to-a-spring-boot-project) with explanation:

"Try putting the..." {insert your bean/s here} "...in a separate @Configuration class. You appear to be forcing it to be instantiated before the ServletContext is ready..."