# A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out a issue for some days but no luck. I came across this issue but not able figure out what is the problem since i am not doing any test here. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516683/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-a-servletcontext-is-required-to-configure-de)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

I am using spring boot

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
   .....
}

public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter
public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ASYNC);
        initCachingHttpHeadersFilter(servletContext, disps);
            initStaticResourcesProductionFilter(servletContext, disps);
            initGzipFilter(servletContext, disps);
    }
```

Now the problem is coming in `TypeToJsonMetadataConverter` bean definition in the following `@Configuration` classes.

```
@Configuration
public class EntityRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
  @Bean
   public TypeToJsonMetadataConverter typeToJsonMetadataConverter() {
    return new TypeToJsonMetadataConverter(typeConfiguration(),
            entityLinks());
  }
  @Bean
  public TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration() {
    return new TypeConfiguration();
  }
}
```