# A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling happens in JUnit that has @WebAppConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, junit

For some reason JUnit cannot wire Spring context correctly:

**JUnit**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationTestConfig.class, CachingConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
public class QueryTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
//...}
```

**ApplicationTestConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence" }, transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-postgresql.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance" },
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = {WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class, WebConfig.class}, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
public class ApplicationTestConfig extends ApplicationConfig {
}
```

**ApplicationConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence" }, transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-postgresql.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.hibernate.query.performance" })
public class ApplicationConfig { //.. }
```

This one (`WebConfig`) should be excluded since `ApplicationTestConfig` has `@ComponentScan.Filter`:

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.hibernate.query.performance.api")
@EnableWebMvc 
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { //.. }
```

Setting `@WebAppConfiguration` in JUnit as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516683/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-a-servletcontext-is-required-to-configure-de) still produces:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory
>   method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is
>   required to configure default servlet handling

Update

This does not work either:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance" },
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(classes = {WebMvcConfigurer.class}, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
```

and

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance" },
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(pattern = "WebConfig", type = FilterType.REGEX))
```

**UPDATE2**
Putting `WebConfig` inside a folder that is marked (in IDEA) as excluded hacked the problem....

Comment: Try swapping @ WebAppConfiguration with @ WebIntegrationTest

Comment: `@WebIntegrationTest` is from spring-boot package. I am using **vanilla** Spring 4 framework...

Comment: Does not work with `@WebIntegrationTest` either