# @ContextConfiguration not bringing in only the config classes specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I noticed that with `@EnableWebMvc` I'm getting the following error when running my tests: `A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling`. This issue is temporarily resolved by commenting out `@EnableWebMvc` then my tests all pass, however I want this in my web app.

I read [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516683/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-a-servletcontext-is-required-to-configure-de) that I could put the `@EnableWebMvc` in another config class that isn't included in the tests(?). So I've tried this:

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.martyn.budget")
@PropertySource("classpath:prod.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource dataSourceForProd() {...
```

WebMvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {...
```

Then in my tests I'm attempting:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class FundRepositoryTest {...
```

However, I'm still seeing the same error in my tests. I know it's the `@EnableWebMvc` as they all pass when I remove this. Have I misunderstood something with how @ContextConfiguration annotation works? By the way, I'm using Spring version 4.2.2.RELEASE for all my spring-* dependencies if that helps.

Below is also the error I'm seeing in my test run:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation isn't only accepting the class(es) I provide but I have found that `@WebAppConfiguration` added to each test class provides the context required:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration // <-- added this
public class FundRepositoryTest {...
```

It's an additional annotation I need to add though but my tests run now.